# I keep getting ModuleNotFoundError where is the issue?

Tags: python, image, pip, google-image-search

So, I'm trying to install and use the google-images-download repo both through: **pip install google-images-download** and **pip install git+https://github.com/Joeclinton1/google-images-download.git**

I've tried installing it as SU as well. In PyCharm when I view packages I do see it but when I try this code:

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download

#instantiate the class
response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()
arguments = {"keywords":"aeroplane, school bus, dog in front of house",
             "limit":10,"print_urls":False}
paths = response.download(arguments)

#print complete paths to the downloaded images
print(paths)
```

it gives this error continuously:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*x*/Desktop/SchoolPython/PythonUVA/Webscrape.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google_images_download import google_images_download
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google_images_download'
```

I think it might not be looking in the right filepath or library but any other repo I tried previously did work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

*edit for versions

```
(3.9UVA) MacBook-Pro-van-Flavia:Webscrape.py flavia$ which pip
/Users/flavia/PycharmProjects/3.9UVA/bin/pip
(3.9UVA) MacBook-Pro-van-Flavia:Webscrape.py flavia$ which python
/Users/flavia/PycharmProjects/3.9UVA/bin/python
(3.9UVA) MacBook-Pro-van-Flavia:Webscrape.py flavia$ pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -----------
async-generator        1.10
attrs                  21.4.0
certifi                2022.5.18.1
cffi                   1.15.0
charset-normalizer     2.0.12
cryptography           37.0.2
google-images-download 2.8.0
h11                    0.13.0
idna                   3.3
outcome                1.1.0
Pillow                 9.1.1
pip                    21.3.1
pycparser              2.21
pyOpenSSL              22.0.0
PySocks                1.7.1
requests               2.27.1
selenium               4.2.0
setuptools             60.2.0
sniffio                1.2.0
sortedcontainers       2.4.0
trio                   0.20.0
trio-websocket         0.9.2
urllib3                1.26.9
wheel                  0.37.1
wsproto                1.1.0
```

Comment: Mac ships with old pip & python by default *still* - if you blindly just call "pip install something" without knowing which pip / python combo was used to install the module, you end up in situation like this.  So question: what does `which pip` & `which python` show in your console ? And are you running the script with `python` or `python3` ?

Comment: I've added the versions in the post and am running python 3.9

Comment: tried - your code works fine.  Do you get that error when you run the code outside off pycharm ?

Comment: Deleted all Python files from MB and reinstalled and that seemed to fix it. Thanks for the help